# Sikuli script is not working on Java 64 bit in windows

Tags: java, sikuli

I am trying to handle some windows popups using Sikuli, I have developed the script and tried it in my windows 32 bit java, it was worked well, but i am trying to execute the same script in java 64 bit, i am getting error like **"Win32Util.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform"**. Can any one plz assist me to work on 64 bit java version with Sikuli.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you just recycling the sikuli-script.jar from the 32bit installation? You need to install the 'cross platform' version of the jar. This should support the 32bit and 64bit JVM from the same jar file.

Comment: @Petesh , i just downloaded sikuli-r930-win32.zip file and extracted to get the jar files and lib. Do i need to download another jar file, if yes, please send me the new jar file link.

Comment: Those files don't support a 64bit JRE. You have to use the sikuli-setup.jar download from the 1.0.1 Service Release to install something that will work on a 64bit JVM.

Comment: just now i installed the sikuli-setup.jar, can i extract it and use the jar files for executing selenium scripts?

Comment: It's an installer. You run it, and choose what you want to install, which is installed into the working directory. It tries to extract the architecture relevant .dll files into the lib directory that it is run from. It will re-extract them if they are incorrect (e.g. when run from a 32bit VM), as long as you installed the cross-platform .jar files.

Comment: Yes, i installed it and took those sikuli-java.jar and libs64 for my script execution, then it was executed well. - Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Steps to work with Sikuli - Java (Eclipse)**

**Step #1** - Download the jar file Sikuli-setup.jar

**Step #2** - Place the Jar file in a new folder (say D:\Sikuli)

**Step #3** - Run the Jar - Two files will be created automatically

1. RunSetup.cmd
2. Log File

**Step #4** - Run the runSetup.cmd file and follow instructions. Click OK --> Select 4th Option from the Form

**Setp #5** - Set Up Fails (Saying Download Failed)

**Step #6** - Now Download [Sikuli-1.0.1-3 - https://launchpad.net/raiman/+download]  patch file [(zip file) - https://launchpadlibrarian.net/156273987/Sukuli-1.0.1-Offline-Setup-Java-option3-option4.zip]

**Step #7** - Copy the Sikuli-java.jar to the (say D:\Sikuli\Downloads)

**Step #8** - Re run the runSetup.cmd and proceed.

**Step #9** - Sikuli-java.jar file is generated. Add this file to the java build path (on eclipse)

**Step #10** - Execute the program.

If Error: If Registry error is displayed about the absense of the Libs folder, Eclipse will automatically add the Libs Folder to the root folder.

If Error:If eclipse throws an error saying Logout

1. List item

   and Login
   Solution : Reboot the machine.

More details can be found at this [link - https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/234720]

Comment: Thanks. My setup completed with the steps you gave.

Answer (score 0):

resolved in latest version here https://launchpad.net/sikuli/sikulix/1.0.1/+download/sikuli-setup.jar