# Don't see sikuli-java lib in maven local repo

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sikuli, slave

I have sikuli maven project, which i want start at Jenkins slave, but when i try build it, console show such massage :

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ZIL_SIK: Could not resolve dependencies for project ZIL_SIK:ZIL_SIK:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.sikuli:sikuli-java:jar:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

sikuli-java.jar installed by such script:

mvn install:file-install -Dfile=sikuli-java.jar -DgroupId=org.sikuli -DartifactId=sikuli-java -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar

Please, help

Comment: Yes. We dont have 'sikuli-java' dependency in maven repository. Download the sikuli-java.jar file from the sikuli site and place the jar in your local .m2 or your organization's remote repository (either nexus or artifactory). And then add the dependency path to your project's pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

POM file (pom.xml) for sikuli-script:

```
<project>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>

</project>
```

For details please visit:  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sikulix/sikulixapi/1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to work with Sikuli - Java (Eclipse)**

Step #1 - Download the jar file Sikuli-setup.jar

Step #2 - Place the Jar file in a new folder (say D:\Sikuli)

Step #3 - Run the Jar - Two files will be created automatically

1. RunSetup.cmd
2. Log File

Step #4 - Run the runSetup.cmd file and follow instructions. Click OK --> Select 4th Option from the Form

Setp #5 - Set Up Fails (Saying Download Failed)

Step #6 - Now Download Sikuli-1.0.1-3 patch file [(zip file)](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/156273987/Sukuli-1.0.1-Offline-Setup-Java-option3-option4.zip)

Step #7 - Copy the Sikuli-java.jar to the (say D:\Sikuli\Downloads)

Step #8 - Re run the runSetup.cmd and proceed.

Step #9 - Sikuli-java.jar file is generated. Add this file to the java build path (on eclipse)

Step #10 - Execute the program.

If Error: If Registry error is displayed about the absense of the Libs folder, Eclipse will automatically add the Libs Folder to the root folder.

If Error:If eclipse throws an error saying Logout and Login Solution : Reboot the machine.

Also see : [Sikuli script is not working on Java 64 bit in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045680/sikuli-script-is-not-working-on-java-64-bit-in-windows/20746986#20746986)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045680/sikuli-script-is-not-working-on-java-64-bit-in-windows/20746986#20746986

Comment: You don't understand me.

I have maven project with tests wich use Sikuli, when i start it from eclipse (rus as -> maven test) every thing ok. But when i try run this tests from Jenkins on this machine(connected to Jenkins like slave), i have eror message.